# ListView with very long Texts does not scroll smoothly. How can i improve performance?

Tags: android, listview

Some of my Views that are created contain very long texts (i.e. 15k characters). How can i scroll such views without any hick-ups?
I was experimenting with creating the Views in a separate threat because i thought the delay might come from the measure process - but the hick-ups remain when the views are added to the ListView.
Does anybody have a different idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Please post all relevant bits of code, like your adapter etc. Otherwise it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem. Generally long texts should not be a problem, something else must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

though you are not giving more information try this

> Listview footer use as your footer layout

```
  View footerView =  ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);
        list.addFooterView(footerView);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html

Answer (score 0):

It's normal to have hick-ups with so much data visible/active/existing at the same time.

Rather then spending much time in an effort to improve the performance of a system that's poorly designed, sometimes it's better to change that design. Here are some alternative solutions that need only one or few texts existing at the same time.

1. Use shorter text for the ListView's item's content and only present the whole text for that item after the item was selected. In a different fragment or activity.
2. Make tabs or horizontal pages that contain a whole text and load the new data when the tab/page is changed (for example a page changes with horizontal fling).

Answer (score 0):

Go through this

```
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TuneAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context mcontext;





    String[] name={"Donald Duck","Peter griffin","Lion roaring","Boo laugh","Cowboy","Tarzan","Bird word","Angry cat","Madagascar Move"};

    int[]image={R.drawable.donald,R.drawable.peter,R.drawable.lion,R.drawable.boo,R.drawable.cow,R.drawable.tarze,R.drawable.bird,R.drawable.cat,R.drawable.meda};


    int[] audio={R.raw.donald,R.raw.peter_griffin_fart,R.raw.lion_roaring,R.raw.boo_laugh,R.raw.cowboy,R.raw.tarzan,R.raw.bird_is_the_word,R.raw.angry_cat,R.raw.madagascar_move_it};
    public TuneAdapter(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        mcontext=activity;

        inflater=(LayoutInflater) mcontext.getSystemService(mcontext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return audio.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final ViewHolder holder;



        if(convertView==null)
        {

            holder=new ViewHolder();

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tuneadapter, null);

            holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tune_image);

            holder.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tune_name);

            holder.use=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tune_use);

            holder.visualizer=(VisualizerView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.visualizerView1);

            holder.play=(ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tune_play);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.image.setImageResource(image[position]);

        holder.name.setText(name[position]);



        holder.use.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new SvaeSDCard(audio[position],name[position]).execute(1);

            }
        });



        holder.play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                  MediaPlayer mPlayer  = MediaPlayer.create(mcontext,audio[position]);

                mPlayer.start();

                holder.play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                holder.visualizer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                holder.visualizer.link(mPlayer);



                Paint paint = new Paint();

                paint.setStrokeWidth(10f);

                paint.setAntiAlias(true);

                paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));

                BarGraphRenderer barGraphRendererBottom = new BarGraphRenderer(3, paint, false);

                holder.visualizer.addRenderer(barGraphRendererBottom);

                mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        holder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                    }
                });
            }
        });



        return convertView;
    }


    class ViewHolder
    {

        ImageView image;

        TextView name,use;

        VisualizerView visualizer;

        ImageButton play;
    }

}
```